# How to know from where my React Native app was triggered?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am building a functionality in my app which requires to know from where my app was launched in user's device, it can be launched from app list, directly from Google Play/Apple Store, or launched by some other app installed on user's device via linking.

I have read about `react-native-send-intent` but I don't think this will be enough for what I am trying to achieve for both android and iOS devices.